# Should I use "in weekdays" or "on weekdays"?

Tags: questions

In my school my teacher do a test for all the class. I have 9.8 in the test because I put *in weekdays*. She said:

> Mariana, we use *on weekdays*...

What is the correct sentence?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here are correct usages that might help:

- I go to the park on Weekends.
- We all go to school on Weekdays.
- During Weekends, I play with my friends.

Your teacher is correct, "**in** Weekend/Weekdays" is never used.

Comment: Don't forget *at the weekend*...

Comment: Well, except perhaps for "**In the week end**ing on 17 June..." ;)

Comment: "In the week" is fine though...

Comment: @Greenonline Largely, I think, British English (not that there is anything wrong with that)

Comment: @TimMottram Could you provide an example where "In the week" is commonly used?

Comment: "I don't want to do that right now - I'll do it some time in the week"

Answer (score 1):

Your teacher is correct.

https://www.englishclub.com/grammar/prepositions-at-in-on-time.htm

On is used for a single day or date.

> "We will be there on Wednesday".

At is used for precise time.

> "We will start at 3 PM".

In is used in reference to sometime during a long period of time.

> "In 2016 we will do that thing"

The difference can be thought of in terms of how specific are you being. I like to think of it like you might think of the ocean. You are either in the water (somewhere), or on the island (specific place in the water) or at the cabana (even more specific place on the island, which is in the water).

It isn't a perfect reference, but it is a close as I can get to being able to visualize a sea of time.

Weekend is a short enough period of time that you still say "We play on the weekend". Where weekend is a singular short entity of time similar to a single day. Two days to be specific, except for long holiday weekends, which are still on, not in or at.

Weeks are not referred to as either in, on, or at. Rather they are this week, next week, last week, some week in may, or the week of something, usually an event as in "the week of the art fair". Week is a singular entity made up of days, but is not long enough to be in and too long to be on.